# What am I doing wrong with Swift and basic geometry

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, swift-playground

When I use the hard coded data for diameter and height Swift runs simulator fine, but when I try and use text values in place using TextField.text.toInt() then I keep getting very annoying error message of:-
cannot invoke \ with an argument list of type $st15

Just where am I going wrong.  I am new to Swift and have only used AppInventor before to create an app with a few thousand downloads.  I am a enthusiastic but probably slow learner, but I will get there if someone would be so kind to help me out a little. Note: Formula is simply PIr2 x h to give cylinder volume.  I want to use diameter which explains why I am halving each time.

```
    let PI = 3.142

    var bodyDiameter = bodyDiameterTextField.text.toInt()  // 3.0
    var bodyHeight = bodyHeightTextField.text.toInt()   // 10.0
    var cylinderVolume: Double
    var cylinderVolume = (PI * (bodyDiameter / 2.0) * (bodyDiameter / 2.0)) * bodyHeight

    println("cylinderVolume")

    cylinderVolumeLabel.text = "(cylinderVolume)"
```

Here follows same code with hard coded values for Bodydiameter and Bodyheight. It all works great in the playground and the simulator.  I guess its got something to do with Integers and Floats, but I'm probably way out.

```
   let PI = 3.142

    var bodyDiameter = 3.0
    var bodyHeight = 10.0
    var cylinderVolume = (PI * (bodyDiameter / 2.0) * (bodyDiameter / 2.0)) * bodyHeight

    println("cylinderVolume")

    cylinderVolumeLabel.text = "(cylinderVolume)"
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code has several errors.

First, and not *really* an error, there's already a built-in constant for π, named `M_PI`.  Use that instead of defining your own `PI` constant.

Next, `String.toInt()` returns an `Int?`.  The question mark means the return type is really `Optional<Int>`.  This is a container that is either empty (`nil`), or contains an `Int`.  If you want to use the `Int` value, you need to unwrap it.  You might want to check that the `Optional` isn't `nil` first, though.

Next, assuming you unwrap the `Int`, you can't perform arithmetic on mixed `Int` and `Double` values in Swift.  You have to convert to all `Int` or all `Double`.  You probably want to use all `Double`.  In fact, you probably don't want to convert from `Int` to `Double` at all.  You probably want to get a `Double` from the text field in the first place.  There's no `toDouble` on `String` in Swift, but there are some other ways to do it.

Finally, you need to say `\(cylinderVolume)` to interpolate the value into the string.  Your code omits the `\`.

Try this:

```
var bodyDiameter = (bodyDiameterTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
var bodyHeight = (bodyHeightTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
var cylinderVolume = (M_PI * (bodyDiameter / 2.0) * (bodyDiameter / 2.0)) * bodyHeight

println("cylinderVolume: \(cylinderVolume)")

cylinderVolumeLabel.text = "(cylinderVolume)"
```

If you want to convert the strings to `Double`s in a localization-friendly way, or detect when the strings aren't valid `Double`s, look up `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, your answer was very clear and easy to understanding, once I had read up on NSString's and Doubles properly.  The PI constant you pointed out will make life simpler. I can now see clear results in the simulator which really does give me the encouragement to push on with my app.  Thank you